# Banner Ad only shows the first time the App launches

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, admob

I have the AdMob Framework implemented in my Game and I use banner ads and interstitial ads. The interstitial ads work fine but the banner ads only show up when I delete the Game and launch it for the first time. Also when I launch the App for the first time I get this message in the console:

```
2018-08-06 21:34:53.778721+0200 game_name[12227:3101070] <Google> Cannot find an ad network adapter with the name(s): com.google.DummyAdapter. Remember to link all required ad network adapters and SDKs, and set -ObjC in the 'Other Linker Flags' setting of your build target.
```

But when I then restart the App, the banner ads don't show anymore and I get a lot (about 10) of error messages like this in my console:

```
2018-08-06 21:23:40.020162+0200 game_name[12216:3098401] WF: _userSettingsForUser mobile: {
    filterBlacklist =     (
    );
    filterWhitelist =     (
    );
    restrictWeb = 1;
    useContentFilter = 0;
    useContentFilterOverrides = 0;
    whitelistEnabled = 0;
}
```

and also some error messages like this:

```
2018-08-06 21:23:36.079086+0200 game_name[12216:3098395] ADD: failed to create cache dictionary at path=/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2CC7FA65-F793-45FA-BD7D-56F1BF847705/Library/Caches/my_name.game_name. key=0x282602b50
```

I have been researching for a long time but I can't find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Did you do step 2?

> To get test ads on this device, call: request.testDevices =
>   @[ @"2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9b" ];

You need to make sure you add your device UUID.

https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/test-ads

If you can't find your UUID, see: https://bjango.com/help/iphoneudid/

There are multiple ways to get UUID, that is just one of them.

Comment: It works now for some reason but I didn't change anything

Comment: Maybe you hit your ad limit then